# How to test Rails app with devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I can't figure out how to test Rails app with devise login.

Message is like this.What should I do? Maybe I need to create spec/model/user.rb ?

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/root_controller_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) RootController GET #index returns http success
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: @user = create(:user)

          NoMethodError:
            undefined method `create' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::RootController::GETIndex:0x007fe643b89878>
          # ./spec/controllers/root_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

     1.2) Failure/Error: sign_out @user

          NoMethodError:
            undefined method `sign_out' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::RootController::GETIndex:0x007fe643b89878>
          # ./spec/controllers/root_controller_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00597 seconds (files took 3.12 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/root_controller_spec.rb:12 # RootController GET #index returns http success
```

spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
        username "Johney"
        sequence(:email) { |n| "johney#{n}@test.com"}
        password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
  end
end
```

spec/controller/root_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RootController, type: :controller do

  before do
    @user = create(:user)

    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end

  after do
    sign_out @user
  end
```

end

spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Customize in Eiicon-Dola
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

Any advise is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)`?

Comment: Also unless you are working on a legacy project you would add these includes in `rails_helper.rb`. The logic being that you can require `spec_helper.rb` for the examples that don't need the whole rails stack.

Comment: Thanks @max . Unfortunately, the modification that you mentioned affected anything. The error message is still same like this. `Failures:

  1) RootController GET #index renders the :index view
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
          
          NoMethodError:
            undefined method `username=' for #<User:0x007fe2491184a0>
          # ./spec/controllers/root_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: Thats actually a really different error message. And most like due to the fact that you have omitted to run a migration.

Comment: Quite frankly you seem like you have no clue at all what you are doing and your setup seems broken in quite a few ways. I would try removing your `spec/spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb` and run `rails g rspec:install` to generate working config files. Then add `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` to  `rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: Appreciated your comment. I'll update along with your advice. And let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 2):

I have done devise login and this code works for me, could be a little help to you

In ***rails_helper.rb***

```
require 'devise'
```

Then create a module with a login method ***auth_helper.rb***

```
require 'spec_helper'

module AuthHelper
 def login_user
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  # user.confirm # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only      necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
  sign_in user
 end
end
```

Use it in controller

```
require 'rails_helper'
include AuthHelper

RSpec.describe DashboardController, type: :controller do

 before(:each) do
  login_user
 end

 context "GET #index" do
  it "renders the :index view" do 
   get :index
   expect(response).to render_template("index")
  end
 end

end
```

Comment: Thanks. but seems like it's not working for me. An error comes up like following.
```
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (***vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rspec)
NameError: uninitialized constant AuthHelper
```

Comment: You should not have to require devise. `require 'rspec/rails'` in your spec or rails helper will load your rails application which requires the gems in your gemfile. Explicitly requiring devise can lead to it being loaded in the wrong order.