# NoMethodError:undefined method `employee' for nil:NilClass for RSPEC test Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, rspec-rails

I want to run the rspec of Tickets controllers, I Have used scaffold and I have made some changes according to my project.
but I am getting some errors. I also have a login (using Devise).
How do I go ahead?

This is the controller-

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ticket, only: %i[ show edit update destroy assign]
  before_action :set_assign_ticket, only: %i[assignid]

  # shows the landing page of employee
  def landing
    @tickets = current_user.employee.tickets.order('tstatus_id, id desc')
  end

  # Service engineer index showing the tickets which are assinged to him
  def slanding
    @tickets = Ticket.where(service_id: current_user.employee.service_id).order('tstatus_id, id desc')
  end

  # Showing tickets list  based on the user type
  def index
    @tickets = if current_user.employee.designation.role == "ADMIN"
                Ticket.all.order('tstatus_id ,id desc ') 
              else
                Ticket.where(employee: current_user.employee)  
              end
  end

  def show
    @tickets = Ticket.all
  end

  def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
  end

 
  #creating a new ticket
  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @ticket.employee = current_user.employee
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.save
        format.html { redirect_to landing_path}
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # updating a ticket
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
        if current_user.employee.designation.role == "ADMIN"
          format.html { redirect_to tickets_url } 
        else
          format.html { redirect_to slanding_path } 
        end
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_ticket
      @ticket = Ticket.where(id: params[:id]).first
    end

    def ticket_params
      params.require(:ticket).permit(:kind, :description, :dev_id, :service_id,:tstatus_id)
    end

    def set_assign_ticket
      @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

This is the model -

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service, optional: true
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :tstatus
  

  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.service_id = 4 # this will assign the service engineer to NONE 
    self.tstatus_id = 1 # this will assign the status to logged
  end
  validates :description, presence: true

end
```

My test cases are:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe TicketsController, type: :controller do
    
    # describe 'GET show' do
    it 'gets show based on ID' do
        @ticket = Ticket.new(id: 1,kind: "Example Ticket", description: "Ticket@example.com", service_id: 1, employee_id: 1,tstatus_id:1)
        get :show, params: { id: @ticket.id }
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end

    
    # describe 'GET edit' do
    it 'has 200 status code' do
        get :new
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
    
    describe 'POST create' do    
        it 'has 200 status code' do
            mock = double('Employee')
            expect(mock).to receive(:employee_id)
            post :create, params: {
                ticket: {
                    id: 1,kind: "Example Ticket", description: "Ticket@example.com", service_id: 1, employee_id: 1,tstatus_id:1
                }
            }
            expect(response.status).to eq 302
        end
    end
 end
```

I am a newbie to rails,
Can someone tell me how to write test cases for the controller above?

Comment: need to login the user before calling the controller actions -- otherwise there is no current user set

Comment: I have tried but still same

Comment: Don't see it in the code you have provided.

Comment: @Sameer_99 Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849945/544113